# Try Catch Block With Input Dialog

Tags: java, input, dialog, try-catch

Is there any way to make this piece of code work? The only problem I am having is that when the user clicks cancel, the message dialog shows up.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something")
    } catch (Exception error) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("Something went wrong.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check the type of exception.

Comment: What would it mean for that code example to "work"?

Comment: This code has a number of errors in it, which is good evidence that it's not your real code. Why not show us the actual code, so we can see the actual problem? You could also simply put `error.printStackTrace();` into your catch block, so see what the "Something" actually was.

Comment: This is just a sample. The actual cause when i used "error.getCause();" was null. I just need a way of making the try catch block ignore when the user selects Cancel.

@Sarnold: by " to work" i mean making the try catch block ignore the cancel select

Comment: *"This is just a sample."*  The sample is rubbish, it is noise. -1

Comment: I believe that's the purpose of a sample. So that i can understand without just being given the answer.

Comment: The type of sample I prefer (and often recommend) is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  I cannot see the point of typing 'something like' the code - if a problem can be described that generically, use pseudo-code and make it clear that it is pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;

class GetInput {

    public static void getInput() {
        String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter something");
        if (result==null) {
            System.out.println("User cancelled action.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("User entered '" + result + "'.");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                getInput();
                getInput();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Typical output

```
User entered 'this code runs!'.
User cancelled action.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: It's a wee bit larger than I hoped, but nevertheless, it works! Thank you very much.

Comment: *"It's a wee bit larger than I hoped"*  In 22 lines the code does it twice.  That is an average of only 11 LOC per invocation.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code so it compiles:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter something");
    } catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong.");
    }
}

}
```

And it works fine when it runs, whether or not I click 'cancel', or 'ok'. No exception is thrown.

I suspect your actual code has something else going on other than what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

When they press Cancel you get a null back. I suspect you are getting a NPE which is getting caught. Check the return value for null.

Comment: Andrew Thompson just posted some code above, which does what you have said. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
    //some code ;)                 
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, " erreur !!! :" + e.getMessage());   
}
```